# the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by $6/7(x^2 + xy/2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by 
>   $$f(x, y) =
> \begin{cases} 
> \frac{6}{7}\left(x^2 + \frac{xy}{2}\right), & 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 2; \\\ 
> 0, & \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}$$ 
>   d. Find $P(Y > 1/2|X < 1/2)$

$P(X < 1/2, Y > 1/2) =  \int 6/7(x^2 +xy/2)dydx$

$P(X<1/2) = \int 6/7(2x^2 +x)dx$

So I get the conditional probability and the limits of integration but I am confused here, how do we find $P(X<1/2) = 6/7(2x^2+x)dx$? Not sure how to go about finding this, any ideas??

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are given the joint density function, you can find the marginal density function of $X$ by integrating $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over $y$:
$$f_X(x)=\int_0^2  \frac67(x^2 + xy/2)\,dy=\dfrac{6}{7}\left(x^2y\biggm|_0^2+x\frac{y^2}{4}\biggm|_0^2\right)=\frac67(2x^2+x).$$